# PWM vs. PPL in L298 motor controller

Tags: motor, pwm, h-bridge, pll, l298

I am currently developing a small robot project. The motor driver I have uses a L298 motor driver IC. It supports two methods of control, PWM and PLL and it is configurable with on-board jumpers on my board. What is the difference between the two in motor control? I understand how PWM works, but PLL got me thinking. Should I consider PLL?

For reference, it seems that they work in the same way: http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php?title=Arduino_Motor_Shield_(L298N)_(SKU:DRI0009)#Sample_Code

Also, here is the L298 datasheet, but it doesn't mention anything about PLL: http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000240.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer isn't correct. f.e. L298 motor shiled has PWM and PLL too. look at [L298 wiki](http://www.elecfreaks.com/wiki/index.php?title=L298_Motor_Shield).
Main difference is that with PLL you controlling speed and direction at one pin from -255 to 255 and second pin HIGH/LOW sets only enable/disable motor (you must switch pins as wiki says). With PWM you controlling speed with one pin and direction with second pin.

For me PLL works better than PWM, where I had problems that one of motor starts later.

Comment: There is no PLL mode because the board does not have any parts needed for a PLL.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Phase Locked Loop (PLL) on that board, and I can't think of any other "PLL" that could possibly apply. Looking at the [schematic](http://www.dfrobot.com/image/data/DRI0009/Arduino%20L298%20Shield%20Sch.pdf), the "PLL" mode that is described in the wiki you linked to is ***just swapping the enable and direction pins***. That's it.

You can see that this is all that those jumpers do by looking at the example code. Notice how the only difference between the two programs is lines 2-5. The only difference is that the enable and motor pin numbers have different values.

Comment: I'm so disappointed right now :P Why would they do that? On their other boards they also include jumpers that switch between microcontroller pins, but it's always obvious.